# Set default input Vector Features in model

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have a Graphical Model with ~10 input Vector Features. Every time i execute it I have to set all 10 features manually. Isnt there a way to set default input values so I dont have to point at the same 10 feature classes each time?

[image]

Comment: Execute it with PyQGIS or qgis_process ?

Comment: Feature request for this function: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39928

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be default option available. Though after the first successful run, the model generally retains the last used option,if the project has been saved.